# How to make Play framework application run SQL script before executing controllers CRUD API method?

Tags: java, h2, slick, play-framework-2.7

I am creating a new play framework application and using slick to connect to h2 database. But when I am running the application and accessing the data it says table is not found. I expect that it should run the 1.sql file available in conf/evolutions/default folder.

Basically play.evolutions is not working.

following is my application.conf file

```
slick.dbs.default.driver = "slick.jdbc.MySQLProfile$"
slick.dbs.default.db.driver = "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"
slick.dbs.default.db.url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/playscalaslickexample"
slick.dbs.default.db.user = ""
slick.dbs.default.db.password = ""

# Evolutions
# ~~~~~
# You can disable evolutions if needed
play.evolutions.enabled=true
play.evolutions.autoApply=true

# You can disable evolutions for a specific datasource if necessary
play.evolutions.db.default.enabled = true
```

And I have **1.sql** file in **evolutions.default** folder

I also tried to change the folder path like **evolutions.playscalaslickexample**. Still I don't see any change.

Answer (score 0):

Add evolutions and jdbc into your dependencies list. Also the 1.sql script should be located in the conf/evolutions/{database name} or conf/evolutions/default directory of your application. Evolutions are automatically activated. If your database schema is not up to date, you need to start the application and try localhost:9000 on the browser an error page will come where you synchronize your database schema by running the appropriate SQL script.

You can also refer documentation https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.x/Evolutions

Please follow the below steps, this might help you

1. Keep 1.sql inside evolutions->default
2. Add below lines in application.conf

   play.evolutions.enabled = false
3. Create test.conf inside conf, if you are using mysql copy below lines in test.conf

   slick.dbs.default.driver = "slick.driver.MySQLDriver$"
   slick.dbs.default.db.url = "jdbc:h2:mem:test;MODE=MySQL;DATABASE_TO_UPPER=false;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1"
   slick.dbs.default.db.user = ""
   slick.dbs.default.db.password = ""
4. Add below line in your build.sbt,

   javaOptions in Test += "-Dconfig.file=conf/test.conf"

   libraryDependencies ++= Seq(evolutions)

Comment: I tried your suggestion. But I don't see any change. Please let me know what am I missing here?

Comment: I changed database from h2 to mysql. Does it matter?

Comment: I updated my answer and added few steps which you can follow